# Place a WCF service in the CDN endpoint?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

Is it any way of placing a WCF service in an Azure CDN Endopint? Or is it only valid to place static content?

It would be useful becasue I have a web frontend that constantly communicates with the WCF service.

If not, any suggestion on how to decrease delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run redundant WCF services in Azure, you create a WCF Service Web Role project and deploy it. Within the configuration, you can scale the deployment up to meet load. You can create and deploy multiple roles per package with each role having its separate instance count.

If you want the service to be distributed across multiple regions, you have to use the [Azure Traffic Manager](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/networking/traffic-manager/) which handles directing traffic based on location or in a round robin format.

Comment: Let's suppose I have 5 instances of the same web role. Is it necessary to set up Azure Traffic Manager? Or is it only necessary when distributing traffic across different regions?
By the way, is there any way to scale instances up automatically?

Comment: Traffic Manager is only important when trying to load-balance things between regions.  Check out www.paraleap.com for auto-scaling of Web Roles in Azure

Comment: You only need Traffic Manager to load balance across regions. Within the same region, you scale by increasing the instance count. For autoscaling, take a look at the [Azure Auto-Scaling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680892(v=pandp.50).aspx)